# Unable to set Environment Variables in Spark Application

Tags: java, apache-spark, environment-variables, emr

I am trying to set environment variable for my spark application, running in **local** mode.

Here is the spark-submit job:-

```
spark-submit --conf spark.executorEnv.FOO=bar --class com.amazon.Main SWALiveOrderModelSpark-1.0-super.jar
```

However, when I am trying to access this:-

```
System.out.println("env variable:- " + System.getenv("FOO"));
```

the output is:-

```
env variable:- null
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]` [is used to](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) (emphasis mine):

> Add the environment variable specified by EnvironmentVariableName to the **Executor process**.

It won't be visible on the driver, excluding `org.apache.spark.SparkConf`. To access it using `System.getenv` you have do it in the right context, for example from a task:

```
sc.range(0, 1).map(_ => System.getenv("FOO")).collect.foreach(println)
```

```
bar
```

Comment: This took me a couple of hours to realize - and may help others.  System.getProperty won't work, but System.getenv does work!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a Spark environment variable using `SparkConf`. You'll have to use `SparkConf` to fetch it as well

```
sc.getConf.get("spark.executorEnv.FOO")
```